# Averaging timestamps in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, average

Simple question really....

How do I average timestamps in an SQL query??

The column format is set to TIME

and the values are as follows.

```
00:01:32
00:02:22
00:02:14
00:01:35
00:01:19
```

I simply want to add up the minutes and seconds, and calculate the average time spent on a task

So in this instance it would be 542 seconds / 5 tasks for an average of 108.4 seconds or 00:01:48 per task.

It seems so simple yet I cannot for the life of me find any answers.  Everything I've found so far uses DATETIME or TIMESTAMP fields.  Im simply using TIME.

Comment: In other DB other ways to do it.

Comment: Added the `mysql` tag based on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming MySQL:

```
SELECT AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(your_column)) AS average_seconds,
SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(your_column))) AS average_time
FROM your_table;
```

- read more about the functions used [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: That returns the average in seconds, how can I turn that back into 00:00:00 format for display?  Sorry for the noobish question

Comment: See the second column.